# Sometimes my touchpad changes so that "tap" becomes "start drag" rather than "click". How can I fix this without a reboot?

Tags: touchpad, dell-xps

I have a 2015 Dell XPS (new style), and sometimes it exhibits the above behaviour.  Typically once a week or so.  I've not noticed any common pattern that triggers it.

A reboot always fixes it, but is seldom convenient!

I've tried disabling/reenabling the touchpad in decive manager etc, to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: Physically clean it, and check for driver updates and/or BIOS updates on Dell's website.

Comment: I did try all of these things multiple times, but it made no difference.  I've had no problems for a few months now though, so I assume Dell or Microsoft finally fixed something.

Answer (score 1):

Go to control panel and uninstall the driver for the touchpad. Go to Dell's site and download the driver for your model laptop. You can open the program for the touchpad and modify the settings for it. It could be that another piece of software or service is interfering. Try doing a clean boot of your pc - as seen here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929135. Once you do that go, start enabling different startup items until you find the culprit.

Comment: But when it's at least a week between instances, and sometimes more like a month, "enabling different items until you find the culprit" doesn't really work!

Comment: Driver re-install is probably your best bet. This is a fairly common problem with touch pads. Have you run Dell diagnostics on it?

Comment: I did try all of these things multiple times, but it made no difference.  I've had no problems for a few months now though, so I assume Dell or Microsoft finally fixed something.

Answer (score 0):

This no longer seems to be a problem (after being plagued by it for a couple of years), so I assume Dell or Microsoft finally fixed something.  If you're having the issue make sure everything from Dell and Windows is up to date and if you're lucky it might fix things for you.